# JSON could not be serialized because of error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.[Swift 4.2]

Tags: ios, json, swift, post, alamofire

how is it possible to send a POST request with nested object like Array of dictionary as Parameter in the HTTP body with Alamofire 5? I failed to convert the object in correct format by JSONSerialization , Don't know what to do next ?

**My JSON Object which need to pass as a parameter**

```
{
"OrderProducts": [
        {
            "ProductId": 2,
            "PrimaryModifierId": 20,
            "SecondaryModifierId": 13,
            "ProductBasePrice": 100,
            "ProductDiscount": 10,
            "Quantity": 3,
            "Total": 270
        },
        {
            "ProductId": 3,
            "PrimaryModifierId": 1,
            "SecondaryModifierId": 6,
            "ProductBasePrice": 120,
            "ProductDiscount": 10,
            "Quantity": 2,
            "Total": 216
        }
    ],
    "OrderDeals": [
        {
            "DealId": 1,
            "DealPrice": 2299,
            "Quantity": 3,
            "Total":6897
        },
        {
            "DealId": 2,
            "DealPrice": 1299,
            "Quantity": 1,
            "Total":1299
        }
    ],
   "OrderDetail": {
            "UserId": 5,
            "PaymentMethodId": 1,
            "OrderPromoCodeId": 1,
            "AddressId": 12,
            "ProductTotal": 700,
            "DealTotal": 500,
            "SubTotal": 1200,
            "ShippingCharges": 300,
            "Tax": 100,
            "TotalPrice": 1600
        },
    "PaymentDetail": {
            "LastFour": 1234,
            "TransactionReference": "sad",
            "TransactionStatus": "Aproved"
        }
```

}

**My Post Request Function**

```
 func OrderCreate(OrderProduct:[[String:Any]] , PaymentDetail:[String:Any], OrderDetail:[String:Any], OrderDeals:[[String:Any]],  completionHandler:@escaping (_ success:OrderCreateModelClass.OrderCreateModel?, Error?) -> ()){

    let header : HTTPHeaders = [
                Api.Params.contentType:Api.Params.applicationJSON,
               Api.Params.authorization:requestManager.instance.getToken!
            ]

    let params : [String:Any] = [
        "OrderProducts" : OrderProduct ,
        "OrderDeals" : OrderDeals,
        "OrderDetail" : OrderDetail,
        "PaymentDetail" : PaymentDetail
    ]

    manager.request(Api.CONSTANTS_METHODS.ORDER_CREATE_API, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON { (response) in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(let validResponse):
                        guard let res = validResponse as? [String:Any] else {return}
                        if ((res["flag"] as? Int) != nil) {
                        let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: validResponse.self, options: [])
                            let resultObject = try! JSONDecoder().decode(OrderCreateModelClass.OrderCreateModel.self, from: data)
                        completionHandler(resultObject,nil)
                        } else {
                        completionHandler(nil,nil)
                        }
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print("FailedNot")
                        switch (response.response?.statusCode) {
                        case 404:
                            print("not Found")
                        case 401:
                            print("unauthorized")
                        case 408:
                            print("request timeout")
                        case 406:
                            print("Unable to format response according to Accept header")
                        completionHandler(nil,error)
                        default:
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

**The Error im getting**

[image]

**My Badly Formatted Json object looks like this(Printed after convertion)**

[image]

**Edited:**

**Func looks like this after Dilan's Solution(But Still giving the same error)**

```
func OrderCreate(OrderProduct:[[String:Any]] , PaymentDetail:[String:Any], OrderDetail:[String:Any], OrderDeals:[[String:Any]],  completionHandler:@escaping (_ success:OrderCreateModelClass.OrderCreateModel?, Error?) -> ()){

    let header : HTTPHeaders = [
                Api.Params.contentType:Api.Params.applicationJSON,
               Api.Params.authorization:requestManager.instance.getToken!
            ]

    var products = [Parameters]()
    var deals = [Parameters]()

    OrderProduct.forEach { (product) in
            let item:Parameters = [
            "ProductId": product["ProductId"] as? Int ?? 0,
            "PrimaryModifierId": product["PrimaryModifierId"] as? Int ?? 0,
            "SecondaryModifierId": product["SecondaryModifierId"] as? Int ?? 0,
            "ProductBasePrice": product["ProductBasePrice"] as? Double ?? 0,
            "ProductDiscount": product["ProductDiscount"] as? Double ?? 0,
            "Quantity": product["Quantity"] as? Double ?? 0,
            "Total": product["Total"] as? Double ?? 0
        ]
        products.append(item)
    }

    OrderDeals.forEach { (deal) in
        let item : Parameters = [
            "DealId" : deal["DealId"] as? Int ?? 0,
            "DealPrice" : deal["DealPrice"] as? Int ?? 0,
            "Quantity" : deal["Quantity"] as? Int ?? 0,
            "Total" : deal["Total"] as? Int ?? 0
        ]
        deals.append(item)
    }

    let paymentDetail : Parameters = [

        "LastFour" : PaymentDetail["LastFour"] as? Int ?? 0,
        "TransactionReference" : PaymentDetail["TransactionReference"] as? Int ?? 0,
        "TransactionStatus" : PaymentDetail["TransactionStatus"] as? Int ?? 0
    ]

    let orderDetail : Parameters = [
        "UserId" : OrderDetail["UserId"] as? Int ?? 0,
        "PaymentMethodId" : OrderDetail["PaymentMethodId"] as? Int ?? 0,
        "OrderPromoCodeId" : OrderDetail["OrderPromoCodeId"] as? Int ?? 0,
        "AddressId" : OrderDetail["AddressId"] as? Int ?? 0,
        "ProductTotal" : OrderDetail["ProductTotal"] as? Int ?? 0,
        "DealTotal" : OrderDetail["DealTotal"] as? Int ?? 0,
        "SubTotal" : OrderDetail["SubTotal"] as? Int ?? 0,
        "ShippingCharges" : OrderDetail["ShippingCharges"] as? Int ?? 0,
        "Tax" : OrderDetail["Tax"] as? Int ?? 0,
        "TotalPrice" : OrderDetail["TotalPrice"] as? Int ?? 0
    ]

    let params : [String:Any] = [
        "OrderProducts" : products ,
        "OrderDeals" : deals,
        "OrderDetail" : orderDetail,
        "PaymentDetail" : paymentDetail
    ]



    manager.request(Api.CONSTANTS_METHODS.ORDER_CREATE_API, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON { (response) in


                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(let validResponse):
                        guard let res = validResponse as? [String:Any] else {return}
                        if ((res["flag"] as? Int) != nil) {
                        let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: validResponse.self, options: [])
                            let resultObject = try! JSONDecoder().decode(OrderCreateModelClass.OrderCreateModel.self, from: data)
                        completionHandler(resultObject,nil)
                        } else {
                        completionHandler(nil,nil)
                        }
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print("FailedNot")
                        switch (response.response?.statusCode) {
                        case 404:
                            print("not Found")
                        case 401:
                            print("unauthorized")
                        case 408:
                            print("request timeout")
                        case 406:
                            print("Unable to format response according to Accept header")
                        completionHandler(nil,error)
                        default:
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: why `OrderProduct:[[String:Any]]`?  check `OrderProduct:[String:Any]` in parameter

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha because OrderProduct and OrderDeal is Array Of Dictionary .. you can see it Printed Object Image just above your comment

Answer (score 1):

In alamofire we cannot convert these kind of json(with nested arrays) directly.You should convert its objects to Parameters from inner to outer..

Before you add **OrderProduct** to **params** , you need to loop OrderProduct array and create Alamofire Parameter objects array and then you can add that array to your param array,

```
var products:[Parameters] = [:]

OrderProduct.forEach { (product) in

    let item:Parameters = [
        "ProductId": product["ProductId"] as? Int ?? 0,
        "PrimaryModifierId": product["PrimaryModifierId"] as? Int ?? 0,
        "SecondaryModifierId": product["SecondaryModifierId"] as? Int ?? 0,
        "ProductBasePrice": product["ProductBasePrice"] as? Double ?? 0,
        "ProductDiscount": product["ProductDiscount"] as? Double ?? 0,
        "Quantity": product["Quantity"] as? Double ?? 0,
        "Total": product["Total"] as? Double ?? 0
    ]

    products.append(item)

}
```

for Order details

```
var orderDetails:Parameters = [

            "UserId": OrderDetail["UserId"] as? Int ?? 0,
            //other fields
]
```

Do the same thing for other needed params,and then you can create your params with these pre created parameters.

```
let params : [String:Any] = [
        "OrderProducts" : [products] ,//pre created param array
        "OrderDeals" : OrderDeals,
        "OrderDetail" : orderDetails, // pre created param
        "PaymentDetail" : PaymentDetail
    ]
```

I think you got it

Comment: Thanks for the comment ... Gonna try it .. will update you further (y)

Comment: sorry for my english. very first you need to create Parameter object from very bottom of json response object. then you can add it to arrays .that is the theory

Comment: How can i object map the OrderDetail Object ..as it is not an Array but a Dictionary ... can you show me ?

Comment: updated the answer, please check.you can create parameter object derectly.then assign to main

Comment: can you add the code after modify and the console output

Comment: Check Edited Version

Comment: bro did you check my edit ? I'm still stucked at it :(